# Linear encoding of a feed forward neural network

Tags: machine-learning, linear-programming, software-verification

I was reading [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.07351.pdf) about reachability analysis of a feed forward neural network (FFNN). The paper encodes a FFNN as a linear programming problem. Suppose $x^{(i)}$ is the vector output of the ith layer, $W^{(i)}$ is the weight matrix corresponding to layer i, and $b^{(i)}$ is the bias vector. So by definition, the output of the ith layer, $x^{(i)}$, should be $x_j^{(i)} = W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)} + b_j^{(i)}$.

On page 4,  under definition 7, I understand the constraint $x_j^{(i)} \ge W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)} + b_j^{(i)}$.

But for the next constraint, I don't get where $\delta^{(i)}$ and M come from? I thought the constraint $x_j^{(i)} \le W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)} + b_j^{(i)} + M\delta^{(i)}_j$ was because the FFNN is considered to have a ReLU activation function, so the $M\delta^{(i)}_j$ will bring the value upto 0 in case $W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)} + b_j^{(i)}$ is negative. But how are they chosen and why is $x_j^{(i)} \le M(1 - \delta^{(i)}_j$)

References

1. [An approach to reachability analysis for feed-forward
   ReLU neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.07351.pdf) by Alessio Lomuscio, Lalit Maganti (June 2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that $\delta_j^{(i)}=1$ means that the input to the ReLU was negative (so its output is zero), and $\delta_j^{(i)}=0$ means that the input to the ReLU was positive (so its output is positive).

You can then verify that both equations make sense.  In particular, I suggest you consider separately the case where $\delta_j^{(i)}=0$ (and thus $W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)}+b_j^{(i)} \ge 0$ from the case where $\delta_j^{(i)}=1$ (and thus $W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)}+b_j^{(i)} \le 0$).  You will see that this program correctly captures the constraints for both cases, forcing $x^{(i)}_j = W_j^{(i)}x^{(i-1)}+b_j^{(i)}$ in the former case and forcing $x^{(i)}_j = 0$ in the latter case, which correctly captures the behavior of the neural network and the ReLU unit.